# Have Samba hide all folders by default

Tags: samba

I want to explicitly specify the folders that Samba makes visible.

For example, imagine a Samba share has folders 1, 2, 3, ..., 10.  How do I tell Samba to make all folders invisible (i.e., hidden), except for folder 10?

Answer (score 1):

By default it already does hide all the directories.  You specify in the `/etc/samba/smb.conf` file at the bottom how you want the shares to be.  Here is an example:

```
[Share_Name]
   path = "/path/to/folder/10"
   directory mask = 0775
   create mask = 0775
   browseable = yes
   writeable = yes
   guest ok = yes
   admin users = <username>
```

As long as folders 1-9 are not in folder 10, there would only be access to folder 10.

If you want to hide the folder from showing up as a share by default but still be able to access change the following line of the share of

```
browseable = yes
```

to

```
browseable = no
```

and restart Samba `sudo systemctl restart smbd.service`.  Then you can still access it via `\\fqdn.name\Share_Name`

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer: there are more directories and I need all the directories to be available (just some of them hidden).  For example, if there are 100 subdirectories, and subdirectories 91-100 are visible.  But the user can still enter into directories 1-90 (they are just not visible).

Comment: @scaramouche Modified my answer.  Hope that helps!